# Entity Framework Generated SQL - Table per Type - Performant?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-4, table-per-type

I am changing my old ADO.Net ways for the Entity Framework. My Products class is made up from about 20 tables (3 of which I have combined so far into the single class), there are 5 Product type tables also, so I have made the Product class Abstract and each type has its own class using the lovely inheritance that the Entity Framework provides using the Table per Type methodology as below. So effectively 3 tables on a product class and 5 product type tables, each with its own class derived from Product.

```
<there was a screenshot here, I don't have the rep to post it though!>
```

I have been keeping an eye on what this EDM is doing under the covers with the SQL Server Profiler as I've been working. When I run a simple Linq to Entities Query as below:

```
var model = from p in Product.Products
                    where p.archive == false && ((Prod_ID == 0) || (p.ID == Prod_ID))
                    select p;
```

Which brings back all types of products that are not archived, and may potentially have an ID search in there as well, the sql profiler shows me an **800 line** piece of SQL!!

Is this normal? And is this performant? Or have I sent the Entity Framework crazy?

```
<I tried to post the SQL too, but there was too much of it for the post>
```

So please, just a sanity check and any advice!

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity Framework can kick out some very large queries, but generally the SQL Server query optimiser does its thing and the query executes with the server barely noticing.

Beyond being generally sensible, sensible I personally tend not to worry about performance and optimisation until a performance analysis tells me I've got a bottleneck; if you're already using SQL profiler, does the query take a relatively long time to execute? Have you had a look at the execution plan and does it look ok?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The query (which is still in its infancy, as I have some 17 more tables to add to my class (of course, not all of these will be recalled at 1 time)), when I execute it in SQL Management Studio takes 4 seconds to run first off, then 1 second after that on subsequent runs.The Actual Execution Plan is a dizzying collection of nested loops,index scans & scaler computations, although nothing leaps out as a bottleneck. I think I am just pulling down too much of the Products class. If performance becomes a problem, would you suggest using Stored Procs & Function Imports?

Comment: Hmmm - a second could be quite a long time for a query which would be executed heavily; maybe you could 1. remove any tables which basically boil down to enumeration values, 2. write a SP which does the same query and see if it executes any faster, 3. write a covering index for the tables in question and see if that helps, or 4. look again at your `Products` class design and how the class is used and see if you can leave some of the class' elements to be lazy-loaded after an initial load.